# Creating aliases for struct members

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```cpp
struct context {
  int a, b;
};

int fn(struct context *c) {
  // create local aliases
  int &a = c->a;
  int &b = c->b;
  // use as if these were local variables
  return a+b;
}
```

Is it possible to automatically create variable aliases in `fn` that allow accessing `a` and `b` without `c->`:

```cpp
int fn(struct context *c) {
  // magic line that is not dependent on the list of the members
  return a+b;
}
```

Something that allows to me to do this automatically without listing all the variables.

I need this for a C++ code generator (SWIG), it would allow me to greatly simplify the templates.

Comment: seems like you want `fn` to be a member function actually

Comment: In c++ you don't need to mention `struct` every time you refer to a type; that's necessary in C only. As long as a (forward) declaration is available, `int fn(context* c)` has the exact same meaning. Furthermore instead of pointers pointer parameters you must not pass null to, I'd recommend using references: `int fn(context& c)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer from @PepijnKramer is giving a general modern c++ solution for the issue of accessing data members of a struct/class.

However - as mentioned in the comments, in this particular case **making `fn` a method** is also a good option.
Note that in this case instead of passing the "current" context as an argument (`fn(ctx)`), the syntax changes to `ctx.fn()`, i.e. calling a method of a particular object.
The method can be marked `const` since it is not modifying the current object.

Here's the full example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct context {
    int a, b;

    // Make fn a method enables to access the data members for this object.
    int fn() const {
        return a + b;
    }
};

int main() {
    context ctx{ 1,2 };
    std::cout << ctx.fn();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use structured binding like this (requires C++17):
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

```
#include <iostream>

struct context 
{
    int a, b;
};

int fn(const context& ctx)
{
    // structured binding only has to know how many members a struct has, not even their names. 
    auto& [a, b] = ctx;
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    context ctx{ 1,2 };
    std::cout << fn(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```